# Camel High CPU usages

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

I have a java+camel bases application which is consuming huge amount of CPU. it various from 40-90% of CPU in production. I tried to replicate the issue in my local environment and started 700 routes (file endpoints) and it is consistently taking 70-80% CPU.

I want to know is there any way I can reduce the CPU utilization by configuring some setting while starting up the routes?

regards
sanjay

Comment: Just a suggestion, what if you change `delay` property in all file endpoints? If they are _consumers_ each endpoint polls the directory every 500ms (default), try something like `file:mydir/?delay=5000` to see if CPU usage goes down by reducing disk I/O